# CKEditor: cursor does not displayed on focus

Tags: javascript, focus, ckeditor

Only on *Chrome on Mac* and *Chrome canary on Windows* (Chrome > 30).

When there is nothing in CKEditor (newly created with blank data) or all the text is removed from CKeditor, clicking on upper part of editor works but if I click lower part of editor, **editor would not get focus** - cursor would not appear in editor.(Though you can still type.)
[image]

It can be reproduced on demo of CKEditor itself. go to http://ckeditor.com/demo. Empty the editor then click outside the editor, when you try to click inside editor on upper part. It won't get focused.

Posted the [ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10950) in CKEditor forum, too. But need quick answer so posting here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is because of small height of html and body tag of inner ckeditor iframe.

Red line on your picture is just on it's bottom border, inspect your editor by chrome.

To fix it i added this lines to contents.css

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Always visible vertical scrollbar is acceptable price for me.

Comment: Yes this is a quick and good fix,
However a new ckeditor will be available with this fix or if anyone want to fix this into code here is http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10945.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser-related issue. Event though the caret is invisible you can still type and once you start, the caret is back again.

Edit: There's [a ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10945) for it.

Comment: Yes I can still type but the end user may get confused and after clicking several times he might get frustrated. And yes I too had posted ticket for that https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10950, but wanted a quick fix or patch. So I had asked here. :)

Comment: You can find ideas for quick fix here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10945#comment:6 and when reading: http://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/11f4494597

Answer (score 0):

Open ckeditor/content.css file, find class `.cke_editable` and change it as below css:

```
.cke_editable {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```