# CKEditor cursor does not appear in Compressed version

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

A related question available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179167/ckeditor-cursor-does-not-displayed-on-focus) but with a minor change. And a [ticket](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/5d8d34a#diff-1) with solution is available. But the suggested solution was for full version where the WYSIWYG editor is given as a separate plugin inside the plugins folder. But in the compressed version how can I include the suggested solution?

**wysiwigarea** folder is not available in plugins folder and in some thread I found that is embedded along with the `ckeditor.js`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That [patch](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/5d8d34a#diff-1) is already included in CKEditor 4.2.2 and it works there. Are you sure that you're using the latest version of CKEditor? Check for example [demos](http://ckeditor.com/demo#skin) that it works.
2. In built version of CKEditor all included plugins are merged into the main `ckeditor.js` file and it will be very hard to find their code there, because it's minified.

Comment: Oh! Okay. I have downloaded the version it before the patch was available. The version is 4.2. Anyway I downloaded a fresh copy again and it works perfect.